# Can I make PyYAML apply one %TAG directive to multiple documents in one stream?

Tags: python, yaml

I have a YAML file like:

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !x! tag:x.y,2013:
--- !x!1 &1
SomeThing:
  member: 1
--- !x!2 &2
OtherThing:
  inner: foo
```

I am not sure whether it is compliant, but it is generated by a program outside of my control.

Really I don't care to convert 'tag:x.y,2013:1' into any particular class, so I tried to use PyYAML's `BasicLoader` like this:

```
import yaml
import pprint

with open("file.yaml", "r") as f:
    items = yaml.load_all(f, Loader=yaml.loader.BasicLoader)
    for item in items:
        pprint.pprint(item)
```

PyYAML throws an exception when it reaches the second document.

```
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a node
found undefined tag handle '!x!'
```

Is there an easy way to either tell PyYAML to ignore tag prefixes entirely, or to apply the same `%TAG` directive to all documents in the stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely malformed YAML--each document in a YAML stream is independent from the previous, and may have different directives set on it.  Admittedly the standard is a little unclear on this, though [Section 9.2](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2801681) states:  "Note that each document [in a stream] is independent of the rest, allowing for heterogeneous log file entries."

It looks like the `Parser` class has a `DEFAULT_TAGS` attribute that maps the default tag handles: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib/yaml/parser.py#L76

As a workaround you could either modify that dict in place (`Parser.DEFAULT_TAGS[u'!x!'] = u'tag:x.y,2013'`) or, perhaps better, might be to subclass the base `Parser` class and make your own `Loader` class that uses your parser:

```
from yaml.parser import Parser
from yaml.reader import Reader
from yaml.scanner import Scanner
from yaml.composer import Composer
from yaml.constructor import Constructor
from yaml.resolver import Resolver

class MyWonkyParser(Parser):
    DEFAULT_TAGS = {u'!x!': u'tag:x.y,2013'}
    DEFAULT_TAGS.update(Parser.DEFAULT_TAGS)

class MyWonkyLoader(Reader, Scanner MyWonkyParser, Composer, Constructor, Resolver):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        Reader.__init__(self, stream)
        Scanner.__init__(self)
        MyWonkyParser.__init__(self)
        Composer.__init__(self)
        Constructor.__init__(self)
        Resolver.__init__(self)
```

Use it like:

```
yaml.load_all(stream, Loader=MyWonkyLoader)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail!  Modifying DEFAULT_TAGS in place certainly did the trick.  Subclassing does seem much cleaner.  I might go that route if my ad-hoc script becomes more permanent and modular.